# Question on a stable geodesic lamination on a closed hyperbolic surface

Tags: surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic, low-dimensional-topology

Let me first state a theorem in Casson-Bleiler *Automorphisms of Surfaces after Nielsen and Thurston*.

> Theorem 5.5: Let $h:F\to F$ be a non-periodic irreducible automorphism of a closed orientable hyperbolic surface. Any lift of a strictly positive power of $h$ has finitely many fixed points on $S^1_\infty$, alternating contracting and expanding. There is a unique perfect lamination $L^S$, invariant under $\hat{h}$, such that $\tilde{L}^S$ contains the geodesics joining consecutive contracting fixed points of any lift of a strictly positive power of $h$. Every leaf of $L^S$ is dense in $L^S$.
> [image: .]

What I'm wondering is that each positive power of $h$ has finitely many fixed points on $S^1_\infty$ so each associates an ideal polygon formed by connecting contracting fixed points. Since $L^S$ has no closed leaves, each such ideal polygon isometrically embedded on $F$ and there are finitely many ideal polygons as principal regions. Suppose there are only two $A$ and $B$. Then the ideal vertices of $A$ on the cover are all contracting fixed points and so are $B$. Here's where something contradictory thing happens: If I iterate $h$, then all the ideal vertices of $A$ and $B$ are fixed but they share only one ideal vertex as all leaves in $L^S$ are not isolated. This means that the ideal vertices of $A$ and $B$ are no longer fixed as I iterate $h$. I'm misunderstanding something here. Can anyone explain why this is wrong?
[image: .]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are confusing ideal polygons on $\mathbb H^2$ with ideal polygons on $F$.

To explain this, let me use the standard terminology of *principle regions* for the ideal polygons that arise in this manner, but I'm going to be careful and speak separately about *principle regions (of $h$) in $\mathbb H^2$* versus *principle regions (of $h$) in $F$*. Let me also introduce notation for the universal covering map $p : \mathbb H^2 \to F$.

So, while it is true that there are only finitely many principle regions in $F$, in fact there are infinitely many different principle regions in $\mathbb H^2$. Namely, if $\alpha \subset F$ is a principle region of $h$ in $F$, then:

1. $p^{-1}(\alpha) \subset \mathbb H^2$ has a countable infinity of connected components, permuted around freely and transitively by the deck transformation action of $\pi_1 F$ on $\mathbb H^2$;
2. For each connected component $A$ of $p^{-1}(\alpha)$, $A$ is a principle region of $h$ in $\mathbb H^2$, and the restriction map $p : A \to \alpha$ is a homeomorphism.

These facts are all established in the midst of the proof of the theorem you have cited.

So the statement that there are only finitely many principle regions of $h$ in $F$ is equivalent to the statement that the total collection of principle regions of $h$ in $\mathbb H^2$ is countably infinite, and it follows furthermore that any two principle regions of $h$ in $\mathbb H^2$ are disjoint from each other.

What might be confusing you is the following.

Let's suppose $H : \mathbb H^2 \to \mathbb H^2$ is a lift of a positive power of $h$, and that its set $\text{Fix}_+(H)$ of attracting fixed points has $\ge 3$ points. It is indeed true in this situation that the ideal polygon $A$ with endpoints on $\text{Fix}_+(H)$ is a principle region of $h$ in $\mathbb H^2$, and that $\alpha = p(A)$ is a principle region $\alpha$ of $h$ in $F$.

And while (yes) there do exist other principle regions $B$ of $h$ in $\mathbb H^2$, and while (yes) they are disjoint from $A$, and while (no) they do not share any vertices with $A$, in fact the vertex sets of $A$ and $B$ are disjoint from each other, ***no vertex of $B$ is fixed by $H$***. Nonetheless, the vertices of $B$ will be the set of attracting fixed points of ***some*** lift of ***some*** power of $h$, just not of $H$ itself.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Here's one thing I'm confused about: 
if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ideal polygons on $F$, then by the density of leaves, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are arbitrarily close to each other. So if I lift $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to the cover and denoted by $A$ and $B$, then I thought $A$ and $B$ should share the same ideal vertex. Is it wrong?

Comment: I also thought that if $B$ is a lift of, say $h^3$, denoted by $H'$, then $H' = H^3$. But this seems wrong because $H'$ here is not exactly $H^3$ but $gH^3$ for some $g\in\pi_1(F)$. So iterating $H'$ on $\Bbb H^2$ does not fix any vertices of $A$ but only $B$ and iteration moves $A$ closer to $B$. Is this correct?

Comment: Regarding your first comment: that is indeed wrong. Just because there exist sequences $x_i \in \alpha$, $y_i \in \beta$ such that $d_F(x_i,y_i) \to 0$ it does not follow that, choosing one lift $A$ of $\alpha$ and one lift $B$ of $\eta$, there exist lifted sequences $\tilde x_i \in A$, $\tilde y_i \in \beta$ such that $d_{\mathbb H^2}(\tilde x_i,\tilde y_i) \to 0$.

Comment: Your second comment looks vaguely correct, modulo some notational issues which I think did not confuse me...

Comment: In the last paragraph, why the vertex sets of $A$ and $B$ are disjoint from each other?

Comment: How much do you know about the proof as a whole? Have you read the the proof in the Casson-Bleiler book?

Comment: But anyway, details of the proof are, perhaps, fodder for another question. My answer shows that your "contradiction" is not a contradiction, resting as it does on premises that are themselves false.